# (Supposed) application of Squeeze Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

In my first calculus test of the semester, I had to evaluate the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {\sin^2(\frac 1 x)\sin^3x} {x} \ .$$

---

**My working**

$$\because \lim\limits_{\theta\to0^-}\frac {\sin\theta} {\theta} = 1$$

\begin{align}
\therefore \lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {\sin^2(\frac 1 x)\sin^3x} {x} & =
\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {\sin^2(\frac 1 x)\sin^3x} {(\frac 1 x)(\frac 1 x)(x)(x)(x)} 
\\[5 mm] & =
(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)
\\[5 mm] & =
1
\end{align}

---

**Answer**

For $$x \in (-\frac \pi 2, 0) \ ,$$

$$0 \leq \sin^2(\frac 1 x) \leq 1$$ and $$x < \sin x < 0 \ .$$

$$\implies 0 \leq \frac {\sin^2(\frac 1 x)\sin^3x} x \leq x^2$$

Then, by Squeeze Theorem,

$$\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\frac {\sin^2(\frac 1 x)\sin^3x} {x} = 0$$

---

I have two questions.

Firstly, I understand largely how the actual answer was derived, but the problem is I do not understand why my method did not work. If anyone can point out where I have gone wrong and why/how I went wrong, that will be great :)

Secondly, with regards to the actual answer, the only thing I still do not get is how the lower bound for $x$ was obtained. I understand that since we are taking the limit as $x \rightarrow 0^-$, the upper bound should be $0$, but I am not sure how the $-\frac \pi 2$ came about.

**Edit**

So following several comments from the community, it turns out this part of the question really was not that hard after all. On the bright side, I am probably never getting such a question wrong again :)

Comment: How did you come up with $\lim_{x \to 0^-}\frac{\sin(1/x)}{1/x}=1$?

Comment: Note that the limit exhibited by @Math Lover is equivalent to $\lim_{y \rightarrow -\infty}\frac{\sin y}{y}$ (where $y = \frac{1}{x}),$ which is equal to $0.$

Comment: @MathLover by letting $\theta = \frac 1 x$? Am I not allowed to do that? I thought $\theta$ could be anything.

Comment: You can reduce your method to the limit of $x^2 sin^2(1/x)$ which clearly goes to $0$ since the trig term oscillates between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Shit. How did I make such a careless mistake.

Comment: *How did I make such a careless mistake.* --- Actually, it took me at least 30 seconds to figure out what was wrong, because $\frac{\sin {(\text {stuff}})}{\text {stuff}}$ is so often used that one forgets to check that the appropriate limit operation is being applied.

Comment: Could one of you guys explain how the lower bound of $-\frac \pi 2$ for $x$ was obtained for the suggested solution as well?

Comment: Yes, $\theta$ can be anything as long as it goes to $0$ as well.

Comment: $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ can be replaced by $-\frac{\pi}{4}$ or $-\frac{\pi}{17}$ or $-0.00387$ -- any value a little less than $0,$ as long as every number between it and $0$ is in the fourth quadrant, thereby allowing you to conclude that $x < \sin x < 0$ between the chosen value and $0.$ Remember that for limits, you only need to consider all values of the variable "near" the limiting value. I suspect the only reason for choosing $-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is to help call the reader's attention to the fact that we're in the 4th quadrant. A solution writer who wanted to be opaque could have used $-0.00387.$

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I see. Just want to clarify something here. How do we know we are in the fourth quadrant? Is it because we are slightly to the left of zero and in trig that is like going clockwise from the positive x-axis? Since usually we go anti-clockwise right?

Comment: *How do we know we are in the fourth quadrant?* -- [This diagram](https://dr282zn36sxxg.cloudfront.net/datastreams/f-d%3A3b35321bd6478eefc75c54b2b3487172b342682dd825373c4933e553%2BIMAGE_TINY%2BIMAGE_TINY.1) might help in recalling the trig convention for angles in trigonometry. Small negative angles put you in the 4th quadrant, small positive angles put you in the 1st quadrant. If the magnitude of the angle is greater than $\frac{\pi}{2}$ (radian measure used), then "all bets are off", and which quadrant you're in becomes a piecewise defined function that is often difficult to work with.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Yeah. That was what I wanted to double-confirm. Was not sure if I still had my high-school math with me. It’s funny how when we get to higher-level maths we sometimes leave the really elementary stuff behind. Thanks a bunch! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\,\to\,0^-} \frac{\sin\frac 1 x}{\frac 1 x} = \lim_{u\,\to\,-\infty} \frac{\sin u} u = 0 \ne 1.
$$